# How to enable background printing by default using css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, printing

How to enable background printing by default using CSS or JavaScript from all browsers' default settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. You would have to put the images into actual, absolutely positioned `<img>` tags. Aside from being a very hacky solution, this of course making tiling very difficult.

Comment: then how to keep available logo (which is in beackground because i'm using image replacement method) in print?

Comment: I don't know what image replacement method you are talking about, but as I said, there is probably no other way than making it a real `<img>`.

Comment: image of logo is in a background of a{display:block}

Comment: Well, you're probably going to have to make it a `<img>`.